# How to score two tiled cities in Carcassonne?

Tags: carcassonne

The rules in my copy of Carcassonne state that cities that consist of only two tiles are worth only 2 points.

I played another copy of carcassonne (10nth anniversary edition), and the rules don't mention this rule anywhere and so I'm left to assume that each tile would each be worth two points like a normal city.

My question is, which set of rules is correct (most up to date, I guess)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems like the rules have changed since we bought our copies of Carcassonne. Two-tile cities are now worth two points per tile (four points total) like any other city.

---

I have an old copy published by Rio Grande. In its rules, the following exception is found:

> Exception: a 2 tile city does not get 2 points per tile

A newer copy of the [rules](http://riograndegames.com/getFile.php?id=670) (dated 2008) on Rio Grande's site doesn't have that exception. The same example as my rules is used, but the two-tile city now grants two points per tile like any other city. Seeing as both of the documents came from Rio Grande, it's clear there was a shift.

The 2008 rules were only found via Google. Seems like the rights got transferred from Rio Grande to Z-Man, so Rio Grande wiped their site of Carcassonne references. A check of Z-Man's version of the [rules](http://zmangames.com/rulebooks/Carcassonne.pdf) also show two-tile cities being worth four points.

Comment: Another change: Farming only gives 3 points instead of 4 now. Many of the games I've played have been fights for farms. It seems these changes were made to balance that.

Comment: Yep, city scoring and farm scoring both got changed. Farms have had a couple of changes, IIRC.

Comment: Farms: Used to be you worked these out by looking at each city, and working out who had the most farmers supporting it.  Got changed to looking at each farm, working out who had the most farmers, then scoring adjacent cities.  The 4->3 was to balance that some cities therefore are scored more than once.

Answer (score 5):

In the current version of Carcassonne, two-tile cities are worth 4 points.

But this is not the only rule that has changed between editions - farmer scoring has changed as well. Below are the scoring differences (copied from [here](http://gracefulboot.com/board_games/carcassonne_farmer_scoring.html)):

> **First Edition Scoring**
>
> If a farmer can walk along the field to a city, he is connected to it.
>   It can be fifty tiles away, or on the same tile. As long as unbroken
>   path goes to the city then he gets counted.
>
> For each completed city, the player with the most farmers touching it
>   gets four points. Tied players all get four points, each.
>
> Note that two-tile cities are two points for a knight when completed.
>
> **Second Edition Scoring**
>
> Count the number of farmers in that field. The player with the most
>   pawns inside the field will score for that field. If many players tie
>   for majority of pawns, they all receive the full points.
>
> A field will score 3 points for each completed city adjacent to the
>   field. A city is adjacent to the field when part of the city walls are
>   used to define the boundary of the field (i.e., next to the field).
>
> A player can score for a single city one time, and only one time... no
>   matter how many fields and farmers he has next to it.
>
> Note that two-tile cities are two points for a knight when completed.
>
> **Third Edition Scoring**
>
> Count the number of farmers in that field. The player with the most
>   pawns inside the field will score for that field. If many players tie
>   for majority of pawns, they all receive the full points.
>
> A field will score 3 points for each completed city adjacent to the
>   field. A city is adjacent to the field when part of the city walls are
>   used to define the boundary of the field (i.e., next to the field).
>
> Each field is scored for itself. Therefore, a city may score more than
>   once for a player.
>
> Note that two-tile cities are four points for a knight when completed.