# How does second edition farmer scoring work?

Tags: carcassonne, edition-comparison

Related to [this question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/7/there-seem-to-be-several-different-scoring-systems-for-fields-cities-in-carcasso); I am wondering how “each city can only be scored once” worked in the second edition rules. Second edition, like third (current); scores each farmland as opposed to scoring each city. But if a city can only count once; then how do you treat a city that is adjacent to multiple farms?

A simple example; imagine a competed game where there is only 1 city; and it has 2 farms touching it. Each player controls a different farm. In third edition, each farm would be worth 3 points. What happens in second edition?

I was able to find the rules for first and third editions online; but not second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A city can be scored once *per player*, so in the given example, each player would receive 3 points.

I found the answer while combing through some threads on boardgamegeek.com, as well as in an answer to [this other question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/21044/2602).

From the other answer:

> A player can score for a single city one time, and only one time... no matter how many fields and farmers he has next to it.

And from [bgg](https://boardgamegeek.com/article/51179#51179):

> German 2nd Ed:
>   1) look at each city
>   2) if a player has the most farmers in any one of the 
>   fields adjcent to the city he scores 3 points.

So it appears that while second edition does consider each field separately; it still scores city-by-city, as opposed to scoring farm-by-farm, and for each city multiple players might score the 3 points.

Answer (score -1):

The answer to the previous question is wrong. The farm rule for the Rio Grande Games edition, which you are calling the second edition, is the same as the current farm rule. (Note, some people call the current basic game the second edition. I can find no evidence that any of Hans im Gluck, Rio Grande, or Z-Man Games number their editions.)

The confusion arises from the awkward way in which the Rio Grande rules were written. The writer doesn't seem to know if he's scoring farms, farmers or cities.

From [Rio Grande Games Carcassonne](http://riograndegames.com/getFile.php?id=670)

FARMER SCORING (for supplying the completed cities)
•Only completed cities are used for scoring farmers.
•The farmer must be in a farm that borders a city to supply it.
The distance of the farmer to the city is unimportant.
•For each city a farm supplies, the player who deployed the most
farmer(s) in the farm earns 3 points, regardless of the size of the
city. If players tie with the most farmers, each scores 3 points.
•A farm can supply (score) several cities if they border the farm.
•Several farms can supply a single city. In such a case, each farm is
scored separately, as descibed (sic) above.
When all completed cities are scored in this way, the scoring and the game is over.

Comment: The link does not work.

Comment: Works now, but it looks like that's a link to third edition rules. You can tell because a small (2-tile) city is worth 4 points instead of 2 points.

Comment: There must be more than three editions. The last time I checked a physical rule book, which was many years ago, it had the small city exception and scored farms as they are currently scored. That is, it was a combination of what people are calling the second edition and the third. It seems strange to me that no one has a copy of those 2nd edition rules.

Comment: There are certainly more than 3 printings; but I've never seen anything about a 4th version of the rules. From what I can tell, second edition was very similar to current edition farm scoring; but it didn't allow for a player to receive more than 3 points from a single city.

Comment: As far as finding a copy of the actual 2nd edition rules; I *think* that it was never printed in the US this way. The rule changes were made by Hans im Glück for the German printing, and Rio Grande only reluctantly adopted the newest rule later on.

Comment: I was looking through a Carcassonne thread on BGG. If every post is accepted as accurate, there were at least 6 combinations of farm and small city scoring.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Although I saw people wording the rules in their own ways, I never found more than 3 different versions of the rules mentioned.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81943/discussion-between-gendoikari-and-steve-b).